# Split queue and always run

Tags: laravel, queue, laravel-5, beanstalkd

I have a database table of users and posts. What I want to do is set up a system where a separate queue job is running for each user.

So what I would do is select all users:

```
$users = User::all();
```

And then loop through each user to start a queue:

```
foreach ($users as $user) {
    // dispatch queue job that goes through each user's posts
}
```

Now I have a queue job running for each user. However, I need to have this job run forever, so that when the user's last post is reached, the job restarts and goes back to the user's latest post and continues the cycle.

How can I create this queue system?

Comment: Ordinarily, Queue jobs are intended to handle long-running processes in the background. An example of some common Queue jobs would be things like file uploads or video encoding. I'm curious more than anything: why do you think you need a Queued job to handle retrieving post records? Even further, why would you want the queue to run in perpetuity? Can you describe your use-case a little more?

Comment: I perform actions on each of the user's posts and I need to do this continuously. Know that the list of users is very short and the number of posts is low.

Answer (score 0):

You can have a job broadcast an event at the end that will have a listener attached. This listener will then dispatch a job to do the work again.

```
php artisan make:job LoopUserPosts

$posts = $user->posts;
$posts->each(function($post){
    //your work on your post
    if($post->id === $posts->count()){
        // broadcast your event here
        event(App\Events\UserPostsLoopEnded, [$post->user]);
    }
});
```

The event may look like this:

```
php artisan make:event UserPostsLoopEnded

class UserPostsLoopEnded extends Event
{
    use SerializesModels;

    public $user;

    public function __construct(App\User $user)
    {
        $this->user = $user;
    }
}
```

Then we need to setup a listener:

```
php artisan make:listener HandleUserPostsLoopEnded --event="UserPostsLoopEnded"

use App\Events\UserPostsLoopEnded;

class HandleUserPostsLoopEnded
{   
    public function __construct()


    public function handle(UserPostsLoopEnded $event)
    {
        //now we can just dispatch the job again
        dispatch(App\Jobs\LoopUserPosts, [$event->user]         
    }
}
```

Then of course you need to `attach the listener`. Go ahead and pop open `App\Providers\EventServiceProvider`, and then make sure we add our event and our listener to the `$listen` array.

```
protected $listen = [
    //.....
    'App\Events\UserPostsLoopEnded' => [
        'App\Listeners\HandleUserPostsLoopEnded',
    ],
];
```

Now we have a complete end to end. Once the job is done firing it will broadcast an event. The listener will receive the event once it has been fired. The listener will then dispatch the job again, passing in the user.